# How can i read digits one by one?

Tags: java

I try to read the numbers from the file with scanner. But I can't read one by one. How can i do that?

This is my txt

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

and this is my code

```
ArrayList<Integer>x = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner scan;

    try {
        scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File("d:/deneme.txt")));
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            int y = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println(y);
            x.add(y);               
        }
        scan.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

When you read in nextInt, it treats 000000000000000000000 as 0. If you use `String y = scan.next()`, then parse by checking  `y.charAt(i)`  in a for loop you will check the digit in each location of the number string.

That char must then be parsed id you want to store it as an int, so use

`int x = Character.getNumericValue(y.charAt(i));`

Comment: How can i find y's size?

Comment: I remembered now. My mistake. Sorry. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I see 39 piece of my txt.

Comment: When i try the add "0" my arraylist, it see "48". I didn't get it.

Comment: I should have been more clear, `String y = scan.next()` then get the digit by using `char x = y.charAt()`

By casting to an int you are getting the ASCII value.  Letm e fix my answer to help.